# Limiting assignment value - Choco

Tags: java, constraints, choco

Is there a way to limit the number of assignments for a specific value of a variable?

I'm writing a schedule problem using `Choco [4.0.1]` with courses, teachers and timeslots. The same teacher can teach many courses and I need to define the amount of courses he/she could teach. I was thinking about counting the number of timeslots, like Teacher B can work `12 hours (12 timeslots)`, so I could post a constraint like `arithm()` to ensure that. Any ideas?

**[Updated]**

Here is some code:

```
IntVar [] teachers;
IntVar [][] teacherTimeslots;
IntVar [] courses;
```

For each course there is a teacher and `N`timeslots, so Teacher A can teach {1,2,3,4} and teacher B {3,4,5} and each course has 4 hours per week. Now imagine that A can work 12 hours. I'd like to limit A to teach only 12 hours (3 courses) while B would teach the remaining courses;

I cannot say how many courses has a teacher but how many he/she could teach, so I'm using

```
Tuples tuples = new Tuples(true);
tuples.add(1, 1);
...
tuples.add(2, 5);
model.table(teacher, course, tuples).post();
```

constraint to ensure that he/she is able to teach certain courses.

`teacherTimeslots` is filled with all possible timeslots and I use `model.allDifferent(teacherTimeslots[teacher]).post()` to keep each teacher timeslot unique.

My courses are fixed so

```
course[0] = 1;
...
course[4] = 5;
```

I thought about getting all timeslots for a teacher but when I'm building my model there is no timeslot selected, so I' get all possibilities.

Comment: Can you share any code with us?  If not, then your question might be too broad and you should attempt something first.

Comment: Just assign the courses to each time slot and if anything had been assigned previously act accordingly, i.e. allow only one course per timeslot and teacher and you should be good to go.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've put some code on my question, could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is my solution. I've created a `Timeslot` class to represent a lecture, containing 1 teacher, 1 course, `m` rooms and `n` slots `(m=n)`, so in my model there is a collection of `timeslot` objects for all courses. I used `model.count(...)` to check how many timeslots has a teacher and I put zero as lower bound because a teacher can be chosen or not and twelve times as upper bound.

```
List<IntVar> teachersTimeslotList = new ArrayList<IntVar>();

List<IntVar> teachersList = new ArrayList<IntVar>();

for (int i = 0; i < timeslots.size(); i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < timeslots.get(i).getTimeslots().size(); j++) {

        IntVar timeslot = timeslots.get(i).getTimeslots().get(j);
        IntVar teacher = timeslots.get(i).getTeacher();

        IntVar sumTeacher = model.intVar("sumTeacher", 0, 100000);

        teachersList.add(teacher);

        model.sum(new IntVar[]{model.intScaleView(timeslot, 1000), teacher}, "=", sumTeacher).post();

        teachersTimeslotList.add(sumTeacher);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < teacheresId.length; i++) {
    model.count(teacheresId[i], teachersList.toArray(new IntVar[teachersList.size()]), model.intVar(0, 12)).post();
}

model.allDifferent(teachersTimeslotList.toArray(new IntVar[teachersTimeslotList.size()]), "NEQS").post();
```

I don't know if this is an optimized solution but at the moment it's working for me and even resolution time was improved by coding this. Thanks!